# Extract part from middle of a string using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on a code where I need to get the device id from below string

```
key-vim.host.PlugStoreTopology.Device-0200eb00006000097000029790063053303032344353594d4d4554
```

device id in this is `60000970000297900630533030323443`

Now I wrote the below code where I am getting the `index` of `6000` and the taking the next 32 chars from there

```
    $strPhrase = $plugs.Device
    [int]$check_index = $strPhrase.IndexOf("6000")
    
    $device = "naa."+$strPhrase.Substring($check_index,32)
```

Most of the cases the `index` value is **48**, so I am able to fetch the proper data. but in few cases`(e.g. key-vim.host.PlugStoreTopology.Device-0200e600006000097000029790063053303031343253594d4d4554)` the index value is not same, so I am not getting the correct ID.

Please let me know how to get these values

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. From the two examples you have given the device ID seems always be located at the same offset after the `Device-` sub string, so you could take that as a search basis.

Comment: Something else must be different.  Either you are not starting at the correct location or the key is in a different location or length.  You need to check the documentation to find out what is wrong.  We cannot help.  The code will always correctly get the substring from a longer string.  The substring may not be what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get the value going from right to left if the value you're looking for is always the 32 characters long and 12 characters away from the right:

```
$str = 'key-vim.host.PlugStoreTopology.Device-0200eb00006000097000029790063053303032344353594d4d4554'
$str -replace '^.+(.{32}).{12}$', '$1'
```

yields `60000970000297900630533030323443`

```
$str = 'key-vim.host.PlugStoreTopology.Device-0200e600006000097000029790063053303031343253594d4d4554'
$str -replace '^.+(.{32}).{12}$', '$1'
```

yields `60000970000297900630533030313432`

or use the string `.Substring()` method

```
$str = 'key-vim.host.PlugStoreTopology.Device-0200eb00006000097000029790063053303032344353594d4d4554'
$str.Substring($str.Length - 44).Substring(0,32)
```

yields `60000970000297900630533030323443`

Answer (score 0):

If the string always looks like this (with Device- and then random 10 characters before the actual device id comes), you could do it using the following regex:

```
$deviceString = 'key-vim.host.PlugStoreTopology.Device-0200eb00006000097000029790063053303032344353594d4d4554'
$deviceString -replace '.*Device-.{10}(.{32}).*', '$1'
```